# Adding a True or False column for a dataframe if it matches a column of a different dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am seeing a few answers for this with Pandas in Python, but haven't found something in R. I am looking to add a 1 or 0 OR True or False boolean type column to a dataframe if that dataframe's column has matching values with another dataframe's column.

As an example, say I have a dataframe 'awesome':

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 23 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 15 |
| E | 18 |
| F | 19 |

And another dataframe 'neat'

| Name | Sports |
| --- | --- |
| A | Soccer |
| B | Bball |
| G | Ball |
| N | Ball |
| Z | Volley |
| F | Boxing |

I'd like to add a True or False column to the 'awesome' dataframe if the Name column in 'awesome' has a match with the 'neat' name column.

So the 'awesome' column would be:
| Name     | Value | has_match  |
| -------- | ------|------------|
| A        | 1     | True       |
| B        | 23    | True       |
| C        | 1     | False      |
| D        | 15    | False      |
| E        | 18    | False      |
| F        | 19    | True       |

Can someone tell me how I could do this in R?

Note: GitHub markdown table doesn't seem to be working for some reason, if anyone knows how to fix it into tables let me know... but have created a pic for easier reference:

[image: image for reference of dataframes]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%in%` :

```
awesome_df$has_match <- awesome_df$Name %in% unique(neat_df$Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one-liner `ifelse`

```
awesome = data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:6], Value = c(1,23,1,15,18,19))
neat = data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "G", "N", "Z", "F"), Sports = c("Soccer", "Bball", "Ball", "Ball", "Volley", "Boxing"))

awesome$has_match = ifelse(awesome$Name==neat$Name, TRUE, FALSE)
awesome
#  Name Value has_match
#1    A     1      TRUE
#2    B    23      TRUE
#3    C     1     FALSE
#4    D    15     FALSE
#5    E    18     FALSE
#6    F    19      TRUE
```